# Spring projects with Spring MVC and business and persistence in stand alone projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

hope anyone could help.

1. I'm creating a new Spring MVC project, but i want to separate the business layer and persistence layer in two stand alone projects (JAR projects) so i can reuse them in other projects.
   I'm thinking using spring in the persistence and business projects and spring MVC for web project, but i don't know where to put the aplicationContext.xml file so the MVC project can inject and use any service, and the service can use any repository, and how to start Persistence and Business when the Web project is deploy.
2. Any advice on the persistence project, the web aplication is a multi user aplication and i'm concerned about  the pool connection, which is the best way to inject a session?

Thank you.

Comment: That is two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i end Using a web application context in the Web project and importing the persistence context and the service context.

`<import resource="classpath:/applicationContextPersistence.xml" />
 <import resource="classpath:/applicationContextService.xml" />`